# I am not able to use Geo Location API

Tags: java, geolocation

Getting
`com.google.maps.errors.RequestDeniedException: This API project is not authorized to use this API.` from java side.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt and show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the API key that you are using is restricted.You need to allow access to (your HTTP referrer)to use this API key from your google console. It will work then You can learn more about it from here.  https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey